# JS replace inline background image in specific ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1775971/615477

```
var images = 'images/image_*.png';
var i = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    var path = images.replace('*', i);
    $('img').attr('src', path);
    i = i + 1;
    if (i == 6) i = 1;
}, 1000);
```

It will replace every `img`.

How to make it only replace inline background image in specific ID like below?

```
<div id="mr3" style="background:url(http://myweb.com/image1.jpg)"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly simple to do, not too much different than the current code:

```
var images = 'images/image_*.png';
var i = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    var path = images.replace('*', i);
    $('#mr3').css('background-image', path);
    i = i + 1;
    if (i == 6) i = 1;
}, 1000);
```